# PHP LDAP authentication NOT WORKING

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to implement LDAP authentication into our company web portal. I can successfully connect to the host, but I cannot seem to get a successful bind with my Active Directory credentials. Looking for some help on what could possibly be going wrong. Any help, tips, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$port = "389";

$connection = ldap_connect($host, $port) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if ($connection) {
    $bind = ldap_bind($connection, $username, $password);
    if ($bind) {
         echo "LDAP bind successful";
    } 
    else {
         echo "LDAP bind failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked logs? Any errors, whats **NOT working**? Also are you using the login DOMAIN\USERNAME ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem recently enough and the solution was to add the domain to the username.

```
$isAuth = ldap_bind($ldap_conn,$_POST['username'].$ldap_settings['adDomain'], $_POST['password']);
```

Where `$ldap_settings['adDomain']` was "@your_domain"

Comment: This was the solution. I had a feeling I would need the domain, but in the examples I researched, I hadn't seen the domain appended to the username. Thanks for the prompt help!

Comment: DOMAIN WITHOUT .COM/.NET or whatever :D